# Web browser going too fast, how to control speed?

Tags: c#, browser, delay, clicking

My app needs to click a button on a page x number of times (user defined).
The page works like this: After you click a button, the page reloads with the same yes/no buttons. Using my code, the app goes crazy and starts clicking way too fast and then crashes.
What can I do so it waits until the page reloads?

```
int toGet = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfTimes.Text);
int got = 0;

while (got < toGet)
{
    while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();
    webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("votea").InvokeMember("click");
    got++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a delay, e.g. 500ms, between the clicks inside your while loop by using setTimeout() function